# Is there an easy way to downgrade kernel to 4.14.x in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kernel, 18.04

I've been having a problem with my desktop session dying: describe in this thread:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread....9756&p=1379652

This thread suggest the problem is with the 4.15 and 4.16 kernels:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235027

This problem did not exist with 16.04.x

I do use ubuntu packaged zfs.

Is there an easy way to downgrade the kernel without reinstalling 16.04 ?

Comment: Why would you need to downgrade? Kernels are not removed when you do an upgrade. You can pick available kernels at the grub screen.

Comment: When I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 it removed the old kernel. The only kernel installed are 4.15.0 and 4.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively straight-forward installing a different kernel: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165)

[image: 4.14.67.png]

The latest kernel in the `4.14.xx` chain is `4.14.67`.

That said I've found kernel chain `4.13.0-xx-generic` which Ubuntu maintains very stable compared to the `4.15.00-xx-generic` kernel chain Ubuntu maintains. The advantage of staying on a Ubuntu kernel chain is it is automatically upgraded for you when new versions come out.

When you are on the `4.14.xx` LTS Linux Kernel Chain you must periodically review when new kernels come out and install the new ones manually using the above link.

Comment: But will it work ok with the ubuntu version of ZFS (which is a kernel module) or will i have to manually install ZFS if i go this route ?

Comment: Also you said 4.13 is installable from ubuntu but under 18.04 i only see 4.15.x and 4.4. How would I move to 4.13 ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the issue via buying a cheap amd gpu. Kind of cheap but easier than dealing with the rest of the crap.